# jquery ui dialog nodal messege doesn't center

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I'm new to this as you can see. I have a simple code but for some reason the dialog box never goes to the center of the screen and does not work on Safari. This is the complete code. It only start a message when any key is pressed. Can anybody help me please.

```
    <!doctype html>
     <html lang="en">
       <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

     <script  src="B:/wamp/www/jquery/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="B:/wamp/www/jquery/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">

       <script src="B:/wamp/www/jquery/development-bundle/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>

     <script src="B:/wamp/www/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
     <script src="B:/wamp/www/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
     <script src="B:/wamp/www/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
      <script src="B:B:/wamp/www/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
      <script src="B:B:/wamp/www/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
      <script src="B:/wamp/www/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
      <script src="B:/wamp/www/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="B:/wamp/www/jquery/development-bundle/demos/demos.css">

       <script >

          $(document).ready(function()
         {
         $("#text1").keyup(function()
    {
    $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
        });

        });
     });



     </script>
      <body>
         <div id="dialog-message"></div>

          <input type="text" id="text1"/>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have jquery.ui.position.js, so...

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    position: 'center',
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

...should work

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but i can't get this to work. It only works in IE (not centering it). Safari and other browsers dont even show the dialog. I'm really going crazy on this and i'd like to use this in my site.